# App is crashing Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.abhi.barcode.frag.libv2.R$string

Tags: android

Hello i have some problem with which I am suffering for a week.app is built on fragments when I open the fragment QRcode reader It works fine as soon as I switch to the other and back again, then an error occurs.I think maybe something is wrong with the method onDestroy and onCreateView

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.abhi.barcode.frag.libv2.R$string
        at com.abhi.barcode.frag.libv2.BarcodeFragment.displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit(BarcodeFragment.java:345)
        at com.abhi.barcode.frag.libv2.BarcodeFragment.initCamera(BarcodeFragment.java:338)
        at com.abhi.barcode.frag.libv2.BarcodeFragment.surfaceCreated(BarcodeFragment.java:212)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:559)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:82)
        at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:172)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:671)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1822)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1002)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4216)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:736)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:566)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:536)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:722)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)






@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (view != null) {
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                if (parent != null)
                    parent.removeView(view);
            }
        try {
            view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_qr, container, false);
        }catch (InflateException e) {

        }



 @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();



Fragment f = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.qr_scan_fragment);
        if (f != null) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .remove(f)
                    .commit();
        }


    }
```

Comment: If you give us a code snippet, like around line 345 of BarcodeFragment, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: looks like a `jar` version mismatch. Check the versions of the jars in the classpath.

Comment: yes it is a library for QR code reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to 90% a missing jar or a false binding into the project check oput the preferences of your Project and maybe you need to do some more stuff go to the documentation of the library you are using there must be something that says how to bind the library right

for example i had to add some lines to the project.properties file

Answer (score 0):

A NoClassDefFoundError usually means that you **had** that class in your classpath at compile time, but that class is now missing from the classpath at runtime (because it is just missing, or because you have a different version, like correctly stated in the comments).

Is this a maven project? If such, perhaps you have a dependency declared as `provided` or something like that, and you are missing the library in runtime.

If not, how are you building and running your code? Do you have the same error when running from the IDE?

However, the root cause will very likely to be what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This exact crash occurred with me, and the solution was really simple. I only had to add the required permissions and features to the Manifest which were:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
```